# Gatsbyjs reach-router import error breaking site

Tags: javascript, html, npm, gatsby

I was working on my Gatsby project and tried adding the `React Cookie Consent` package. After installing it and trying to implement it, my site broke down, proving me with this error:

```
   warn ./.cache/root.js
    Attempted import error: 'BaseContext' is not exported from '@gatsbyjs/reach-router' (imported as 'BaseContext').
```

I can't seem to find a fix, nor do I know why it is happening. Localhost is throwing me this error:

```
_gatsbyjs_reach_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.BaseContext is undefined
```

Any help is welcome! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon trying deleting the cache folder by running:

```
gatsby clean
```

If the issue persist, try bypassing the SSR limitation by adding the following to your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({actions, loaders, stage}) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /react-cookie-consent/,
                        use: loaders.null(),
                    },
                ],
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Or using a dynamic import:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const { getCookieConsentValue, Cookies } = await import('react-cookie-consent')

    getCookieConsentValue('test')
    Cookies.get()
  })()
}, [])
```

You can check for further approaches at: https://github.com/Mastermindzh/react-cookie-consent/issues/136

Comment: Gatsby clean didn't do it. Thank you for your answer. The second part, however, did help :)